# Rails Simple Form custom association select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, simple-form

I have a select field and I want to put a custom attribute at it called name, I tried to do it like that:

```
 <%= f.association  :in_charge, :collection => User.lawyer.map{ |l| [l.name, l.id, {:name => l.name.downcase}] } %>
```

It works and generates the extra attribute but there is a problem, the select value attribute get changed to the model name attribute, in this case l.name. I changed places and put l.id first but the id attribute is displayed, they get duplicated, any idea why that happens?

Is there another way to define custom attributes at associations select fields?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the Rails [select()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) form helper, wrapped by a SimpleForm input.

```
 <%= f.input :in_charge do %>
   <%= f.select :county_id, User.lawyer.map{ |l| [l.name, l.id, {:name => l.name.downcase}] } %>
 <% end %>
```

Your code doesn't work as expected because, under the hood, SimpleForm calls [collection_select()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) which doesn't support extra attributes in the option tags.

The SimpleForm readme has the [solution](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#wrapping-rails-form-helpers) as well. But I didn't notice that until I had solved the problem myself :)

Answer (score 1):

For the records, it seems that this is working now:

```
f.association :product, collection: Product.all.map { |product| [product.name, product.id, {data: {description: product.description}}] }
```

SimpleForm version:

```
$ bundle show simple_form
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@a4aa2/gems/simple_form-4.1.0
```