# How do I add HTML attributes to select options with Simple Form Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I need to add a custom HTML attribute to each `option` for a `select` control. I'm using simple_form in Rails. Does anyone know how to do this? The attribute will be consumed by client-side JS.

For instance, I want to do something like this:

```
<%= f.input :group, collection: @groups, option_html: { data-type: lambda { |g| g[2] } } %>
```

Which would produce (simplified):

```
<select>
    <option value="1" data-type="primary">First Group</option>
    <option value="2" data-type="secondary">Second Group</option>
    <option value="3" data-type="secondary">Third Group</option>
</select>
```

Where `@groups` might look like this:

```
[
    ['First Group', 1, 'primary'],
    ['Second Group', 2, 'secondary'],
    ['Third Group', 3, 'secondary']
]
```

Hoping to avoid having to make a custom control/wrapper. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27975639/1536309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the correct way of doing this:

[Rails Simple Form custom association select field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974304/rails-simple-form-custom-association-select-field)

Comment: The posted link says how to customize the <select> tag and the author wanted to customize the <option> tags.

Answer (score 24):

You're close! easiest way is actually not using simple_form here. here's the [simple_form documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#wrapping-rails-form-helpers)

```
<% options = @group.map { |g| [g.name, g.id, {'data-type' => g.group_type}] } %>
<%= f.input :group, label: 'Group' do %>
  <%= f.select :group, options, include_blank: 'Select a Group', class: 'form-control' %>
<% end %>
```

For your exact code it would be:

```
<% options = @group.map { |g| [g[0], g[1], {'data-type' => g[2]}] } %>
<%= f.input :group, label: 'Group' do %>
  <%= f.select :group, options, include_blank: 'Select a Group', class: 'form-control' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 23):

simple-form only:

`= f.input :group, @groups.map{|l| [l[0], l[1], {data: {type: l[2]}}]}`

Comment: Works perfectly! This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking for this!! should be correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A (small) drawback using `f.input do end` method is that any default input html options (like simple form's `required` or `optional` classes or the `required` attribute) and any default options (like `b.use :input, class: 'input-element'`) are missing when simply passing a block to `f.input`, **tldr: the input does not get decorated**.

If you rely on these extra classes and attributes, you'd have to manually pass them in (not dry).

To overcome this I've created a custom input for my special selects, so I can define the body of my select like I want (the `<option>` tags) but the select gets decorated as usual:

```
# app/inputs/select_container_input.rb
class SelectContainerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base 
  def input(wrapper_options)
    options_html = input_options.delete(:options_html)

    # since we pass our options by our self (and have to select the correct
    # option), set `selected` to `''` to prevent rails calling
    # `object.send(attribute_name)` only to set `selected` which is not used.
    input_options[:selected] = ''    

    merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)
    @builder.select attribute_name, nil, input_options, merged_input_options do
      options_html
    end
  end
end
```

Simply call it like this:

```
<% options_html = capture do %>
  <option>bla</option>
<% end %>
<%= f.input :attribute, as: :select_container, options_html: options_html %>
```

The `options_html` is a workaround, because actually it would be easier to pass in a block to our custom input:

```
<%= f.input :attribute, as: :select_container do %>
  <option>bla</option>
<% end %>
```

But due to the way [SimpleForm::FormBuilder#def_input](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/b1da0744ddef55cf323b2e770846df90b61e213b/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L496-L505) works, the block gets carried away before code even touches the inputs. So no way without refactoring simple_form.

All in all this solves the problem with a little bit extra noisy code in your views for your special selects.

Answer (score 1):

For an association select:

```
f.association :product, collection: Product.all.map { |product| [product.name, product.id] }
```