# Assigning attributes to options in a group_select using Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, html-select, simple-form, custom-data-attribute

I'm well aware of assigning data attributes to options in a traditional select box using [Simple Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27975639/3046413) but when it comes to grouped options I seem to be running into some issues. I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6374301/3046413) that explains how to do it sans Simple Form:

```
<%= f.select :game_id, grouped_options_for_select(@consoles.map{ |console| [console.name, console.games.map{ |g| [g.title, g.id, {'data-game'=> g.title.downcase.gsub(/\s+/, "-")}] } ] }, selected_key = f.object.game_id) %>
```

When I try to translate this into the appropriate syntax I get this error:

`undefined method 'games' for ["PS3", []]:Array`

```
<%= f.input :game_id, as: :grouped_select, collection: @consoles.map{ |console| [console.name, console.games.map{ |g| [g.title, g.id, {'data-game'=> g.title.downcase.gsub(/\s+/, "-")}] } ] }, group_method: :games, include_blank: "Select a game", input_html: {class: "boost__game"} %>
```

**Models**

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes: title
  has_and_belongs_to_many :consoles
end


class Console < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes: name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games
end
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Is console an Array?

Comment: Its a model thats in a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with the `Game` model .

Comment: I think the error is somewhere else then...

Comment: Are you sure because it works just fine using the `f.select` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<%= f.input :game_id, as: :grouped_select, collection: @consoles.map{ |console| [console.name, console.games.map{ |g| [g.title, g.id, {'data-game'=> g.title.downcase.gsub(/\s+/, "-")}] } ] }, group_method: :last, include_blank: "Select a game", input_html: {class: "boost__game"} %>
```

Comment: With this code the options for the select box turn into all the keys within the provided in the f.select's hash: `as, grouped_select, collection, include_blank, class`

Comment: Will your collection value be of the format `[['Authors', ['Jose', 'Carlos']], ['General', ['Bob', 'John']]]`. I mean, `@consoles.map{ |console| [console.name, console.games.map{ |g| [g.title, g.id, {'data-game'=> g.title.downcase.gsub(/\s+/, "-")}] } ] }` will be of the format `[['Authors', ['Jose', 'Carlos']], ['General', ['Bob', 'John']]]`

Comment: Yes. So the group's title of the select box will be the name of the console and the nested options will be the title of games. Hopefully this translates your example to my current situation: `[['Xbox One', ['Halo', 'Tomb Raider']], ['PS4', ['Drive Club', 'Last of Us']]]`

Comment: Now, I'm getting what your error is...The error is in group_method. What you get in collection is an array. So it is trying to access that Array.games

Comment: This would work but I still need to apply data attributes to the options.

Comment: Awesome! Everything seems to work. I'm curious though. What is `:last` doing for `group_method`?

Comment: group_method => the method to be called on the given collection to generate the options for each group (required). As this is an array we have to say that the last element in each array is the list of options. Basically we are making use of Ruby's Array#last method inside group_method. For eg: `['PS4', ['Drive Club', 'Last of Us']]` , here PS4 is the main collection and last gives `['Drive Club', 'Last of Us']`. Hence the options will be populated. The [test suite](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/test/inputs/grouped_collection_select_input_test.rb) helped me debug that