# Rails: Multi-Select Image Picker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am using Simple Forms and I have the following multi-select form working properly for both the new and edit views:

```
<%= f.association :attitudes, as: :select %>
```

I can make multiple selection and update the DB -- when I go to the edit age -- I see the selections which are in the DB and have the ability to change and update the DB ---

I am now attempting to use http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/ -- I could not use the above code because as I understand it ([Rails Simple Form custom association select field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974304/rails-simple-form-custom-association-select-field)) Simple Form Collection does not support additional attributes

After much trial and effort -- I now have this working for the NEW view -- thanks to this post: http://www.redguava.com.au/2011/03/rails-3-select-list-items-with-custom-attributes/:

**NEW VIEW**

```
<%= f.association :attitudes do %>
<%= select_tag("task[attitude_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select_with_attributes(Attitude.all, 'id', 'name', 'data-img-src', 'img_url',  @task.attitudes.collect), {:multiple=>true, :size=>5, :class=>"image-picker show-html"}) %>
<% end %>
```

**APPLICATION_HELPER.RB**

```
def options_from_collection_for_select_with_attributes(collection, value_method, text_method, attr_name, attr_field, selected = nil)
    options = collection.map do |element|
    [element.send(text_method), element.send(value_method), attr_name => element.send(attr_field)]
end

selected, disabled = extract_selected_and_disabled(selected)
select_deselect = {}
select_deselect[:selected] = extract_values_from_collection(collection, value_method, selected)
select_deselect[:disabled] = extract_values_from_collection(collection, value_method, disabled)

options_for_select(options, select_deselect)

end
```

My problem is that when I go to the edit view the multi-select does not show the items that are in the DB --- I think it may be something simple that I am overlooking and at one point that it was the selected=nil -- but changing that did not do anything ---

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may have a similar issue (and hopefully this will save you hours of research and trial/error) -- I was able to overcome the problem with the following code:

```
<%= f.input :attitude do %>
<%= f.select :attitude_ids, Attitude.all.map { |f| [f.name, f.id, { 'data-img-src' => f.img_url} ] }, { :prompt => "Please select"}, { :multiple => true, :size => 5, :class=>"image-picker show-html" } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you download the source code or use the `image picker rails` gem? I used the gem, and made my select exactly as your select is displayed (minus the block because I'm not using simple_form). But no images rendered and I get a rails default select box.