# How can I add classes to a simple_form input wrapper in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wrapper, simple-form

I need to add a data attribute to an `f.association` input in a simple form. To do this I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974304/rails-simple-form-custom-association-select-field) and subsequent reference to [simpleform's documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#wrapping-rails-form-helpers). It is easy enough to add classes with the standard syntax, I am wondering why it's proving difficult using a wrapper.

So rather than the standard:

```
<%= f.association :size, input_html:{class: 'sku-suffix-component'} %>
```

I am using:

```
<%= f.input :size, as: :select, input_html:{class: 'sku-suffix-component'} do %>
  <%= f.select :size, Size.all.map{ |s| [s.name, s.id, {'data-code-num' => s.code_num}] } %>
<% end %>
```

Much to my frustration, the added `class` is nowhere in the `<select>` tag (not to mention the missing other default classes and `id` naming convention [`id="product_size_id"`  becomes  `id="product_size"`]). I have tried various syntaxes and placements of the `input_html` hash.

Below you can see the difference in appearance etc. On the right is using the standard syntax.
[image]

And here is the resulting html:

```
<select name="product[size]" id="product_size"> (...)
```

Compared with:

```
<select class="form-control select required sku-suffix-component" name="product[color_id]" id="product_color_id"> (...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution combining strategies that I found on separate posts.

The long and the short of it was to utilize the `map` method but not within  a custom input wrapper.

```
<%= f.association :size, collection: Size.all.map{ |s| [s.name, s.id, {'data-code-num' => s.code_num}]}, input_html:{class: 'sku-suffix-component'} %>
```

This nets perfectly my desired `<select>` with an added class, and the `<option>`'s with a custom `data-` attribute.

```
<select class="form-control select required sku-suffix-component" name="product[size_id]" id="product_size_id">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option data-code-num="001" value="113">onesize</option>
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution and if it is possible than create some link for jsfiddle so we can test and try to find solution

```
<%= f.input :size do %>
    <%= f.select :size, Size.all.map { |s| [s.name, s.id, { class: 'sku-suffix-component', 'data-code-num' => s.code_num }]}, input_html: { class: 'sku-suffix-component' }, include_blank: true %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering, this does work but assigns a class to the `<option>` tag, and not the `<select>` tag unfortunately